# I want to do inner join of some colums but still show the other colums if thats possible

Tags: sql

basically i have a quest to do where i have to get all the details (product_purchase,price_history ,product colums that are name,type,id and price)from just searching for a product id.i basically did

```
select price_history.product_id, product.id, product_purchase.product_id from ((price_history 
inner join product on price_history.product_id = product.id)
inner join product_purchase on price_history.product_id = product_purchase.product_id);
```

right now it just gives me the product id from product_purchase price_history and the id from product and i wanted it to show all the other colums from the 3 tables and want to have an option where i can do an input of the id something like

```
where product.id= %s
```

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT *` to get "all" your columns? Have you tried putting your `WHERE` clause at the end of your query? Those things should work for you.

Comment: select * from ((price_history
inner join product on price_history.product_id = product.id)
inner join product_purchase on price_history.product_id = product_purchase.product_id);
where product.id = 2 like this it gives me an error on the where dont know why

Comment: The semicolon goes after the end of your whole query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM price_history 
 INNER JOIN product
            ON price_history.product_id = product.id
 INNER JOIN product_purchase
            ON price_history.product_id = product_purchase.product_id
 WHERE product_id = %substitutedParameter%
```

But, as you will see, `SELECT *` gives you some redundant columns. It's good practice to name the columns you want in your SELECT.... something like this, I guess.

```
SELECT price_history.product_id,
       product.description,
       product_purchase.vendor
...
```

Comment: thank you so much sorry for bothering!

Comment: i have another quetion about this: if the product was never purchased (product.id not on the product_purchase table because it has never been added) it wont show any of the other colums.  how do i do so it appears anyway altough not existing on product_purchase?

Comment: [LEFT JOIN](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx) is the answer. `FROM product LEFT JOIN product_purchase ON ...`

Comment: SELECT * 
  FROM price_history
 LEFT JOIN product_purchase on price_history.product_id = product_purchase.product_id
 INNER JOIN product ON price_history.product_id = product.id
 WHERE product.id = 1